# How to make "select" display the options in a single column?

Tags: linux, bash, select

I have a random situation, when I use multiple choice menu in bash and add more items to my list selection, the menu does no longer stack up line by line

```
echo "         [?] What would you like to do:"
echo
# End

opt=""
select recon in Enumeration General Web-Recon Services Msfvenom Other
do
opt="$recon"
case $recon in 
Enumeration|General|Web-Recon|Services|Msfvenon|Other)   
        break
        ;;
*)
        echo # Spacer
        echo "You Sure? Try it again" 
        ;;
esac
echo $recon
done
```

What I get looks something like this:

```
         [?] What would you like to do:

1) Enumeration  3) Web-Recon    5) Msfvenom
2) General      4) Services     6) Other
#?
```

However I'd rather prefer if it looked like this:

```
1) Enumeration
2) General  
3) Web-Recon
4) Services 
5) Msfvenom             
6) Other
```

Is there a way of telling the script to do so?
Thank you

Comment: This might help: [Can I change how select options are displayed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203309/74329)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `COLUMNS=0` before your `select` command.

Tested with bash 4.2.8.

Comment: It does not work for me. However it works if I use COLUMNS=1. Wierd.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the following script and make addition based on the requirement,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n  "[?] What would you like to do : "
echo
echo

echo "1) Enumeration"
echo "2) General"
echo "3) Web-Recon"

echo
read entry
echo
case $entry in
    1)
        echo "Enumeration"  
        break
        ;;
    2)
        echo "General"
        break
        ;;
    3)
        echo "Web-Recon"
        break
        ;;
    default)
        echo "Default Action"
        break
        ;;
esac
```

Following is the output for this

```
[?] What would you like to do : 

1) Enumeration
2) General
3) Web-Recon

2

General
```